# how can we export data into mutiple csv files from a single df

Tags: r

I want to export city wise data to csv files, for that i am following a static method as below

```
city=c("NYC","NYC","NYC","LONDON","LONDON","LONDON","PARIS","PARIS")
country=c("USA","USA","USA","UK","UK","UK","FRANCE","FRANCE")
year=c(2000,2000,2000,2010,2010,2010,2017,2017)
df=data.frame(city,country,year)

#1
city<-df[which(df$city == "NYC"),]
file_name = paste0("NYC",".csv")
write.csv(city,file_name,row.names=FALSE)

#2
city<-df[which(df$city == "LONDON"),]
file_name = paste0("LONDON",".csv")
write.csv(city,file_name,row.names=FALSE)
```

same for #3
Please help it to convert into dynamic code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
for (cit in unique(df$city)) {
  write.csv(
    x = subset(df, city == cit),
    file = paste0(cit, ".csv"),
    row.names = FALSE
  )
}
```

**PS.**
Often lowercase filenames are preferred, thus I would convert `file = paste0(cit, ".csv")` to `file = tolower(paste0(cit, ".csv"))`

Answer (score 1):

@snoram's answer should work well, so please consider this just another way to do the same thing. I'm a fan of `data.table`, and one of the things I like about it is calling functions alongside a `by` call:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( df )

df[ , write.csv( .SD,
                 paste0( city[1], ".csv" ),
                 row.names = FALSE ),
    by = city ]
```

`.SD` here represents each subset of `df`; one for each value of `city`.

`city[1]` takes the first value of `city` from each `.SD` (that column will be filled with one value all the way down).

Comment: Nice! Would use `fwrite()` since you have already loaded data.table. What about the following then? `df[, fwrite(.SD, paste0(city, ".csv")), by = city]`

Comment: Definitely, @snoram. `fwrite` will behave a little differently with some column types though, so `write.csv` is just to maintain consistency with what the OP wants. Other than that, `fwrite` all the way :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the `paste0(city, ...` part, that may try to `paste` the entire `city` vector (which will be the city name, repeated the number of times it appears in the original table), rather than a single value.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused but I tried what I pasted above and it worked the same as the your solution, at least in this specific context.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use split to break your df in a list and then loop:

```
for (i in split(df,city)){
  write.csv(i,paste0(i$city[1],".csv"))
}
```